# TCL: Automatically open Debugger with source

Tags: debugging, tcl

## Background:

Today, I use basic TCL console.
To open this console, I run *.bat file that opens the console with execution of some *.tcl source, the *.bat file looks like that:

```
start tkcon.tcl -font "Courier 12" bin/analog_start.tcl 44
```

*analog_start.tcl calls all the sources i need for work

## RamDebugger:

I want to use debugger for TCL, I found an opensource debugger written in TCL.
Yet didn't found any community for that

UPDATE: Just found another opensource debugger: Netbeans

## Requirement:

I need to open this debugger and load "analog_start.tcl" automatically

How can i do it?

P.S. If there's any other good debugger for this, i'll be glad to hear.

Many thanks.
Evgeny.